# Не показывать кнопку "показать/скрыть" если элементов меньше X

Tags: javascript, jquery, условия

Есть скрипт для показа/скрытия длинного списка:
http://jsfiddle.net/pxm85a1y/1/

```js
$('.term-list').each(function() {
  var $list = $(this);
  $list.before('<button class="more_less">More</button>');
  $list.find('.term-item:gt(3)').hide();
});

$('.more_less').click(function() {
  var $btn = $(this);
  $btn.next().find('.term-item:gt(3)').slideToggle();
  $btn.text($btn.text() == 'More' ? 'Less' : 'More');
});
```

```css
.term-list {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu1">

  <ul class="term-list">
    <li class="term-item ">Item 1</li>
    <li class="term-item ">Item 2</li>
    <li class="term-item ">Item 3</li>
    <li class="term-item ">Item 4</li>
    <li class="term-item ">Item 1</li>
    <li class="term-item ">Item 2</li>
    <li class="term-item ">Item 3</li>
    <li class="term-item ">Item 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="menu2">

  <ul class="term-list">
    <li class="term-item ">Item 1</li>
    <li class="term-item ">Item 2</li>
    <li class="term-item ">Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Нужно не показывать кнопку "More" если список слишком короткий (меньше 3-4 элементов).
Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавь в `$('.term-list').each(function(){})` следующую проверку в начало:

```
let li_count = $(this).find('li').length;
if (li_count < 4) return;
```

Это как раз уберет появление кнопки `More`

Comment: Спасибо!
Сработало вот так:
let li_count = $(this).find('li.term-item').length;
if (li_count < 4) return;

Comment: Ну да, ты `li.term-item` дал уточнения, что тебе не просто `li` нужен, а именно с классом `term-item`